# How to import multiple excel sheets in an excel source to SQL using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

How to import multiple excel sheets in an excel source to SQL using SSIS?

I will have to import multiple excel files and each file has 8 sheets. 
Number of sheets on all the input files remains same.

- Each Sheet will be imported to each table.
- Each sheet will have different row # ( Sheet1$A:K, Sheet2$A3:F ..) to start the import process.

How to set this setting in the Excel Source ?

Comment: If all the sheets have the same name, in all the files, you could do this with 8 sources (and destinations if they're going to different tables) in you Dataflow Task, and use a ForEach Loop on the directory they are stored in.

Comment: After all of that you just delete your question? I hope you solved your issue but I also hope you realise you have a bad reputation

Comment: I agree with you, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to import all sheets in an Excel workbook into SQL you can refer to the following links:

- [How to loop over the worksheets in an Excel workbook using Integration Services](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2531/loop-over-excel-worksheets.htm)
- [How to read data from multiple Excel worksheets with SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/)

But you must notice that if the excel worksheets have different structures, then you should create multiple excel source, also if loop through many excel files you should create a foreach loop container to loop over files and inside it you should create another foreach loop container to loop over worksheets.